# Adding configuration to Webpack-based SPA

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I'm writing SPA using Vue.js and Webpack 2. The Node ecosystem is fairly new experience for me.

I need to be able to set some configurations variables, preferably resolved dynamically. In my mind, the solution would involve config file that's fetched whenever application gets loaded. The problem looks fairly generic, but I didn't manage to google anything like it.

Is there any "standard" solution in Webpack world for this, or at least any established good practices?

Answer (score 0):

Say you store your config variables in a JSON file, config.json.

```
{
  "some": "123",
  "configs": "456",
  "here": "789"
}
```

Require your config file with file-loader in your application.
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader

```
// Require config file
// File-loader returns the public URL for your file required here
var configURL = require("file-loader!./config.json");
```

Load your config.json with a simple XHR before you initialize your Vue application.

```
// Create XHR
var configXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
configXHR.open("GET", configURL, false);    // Synchronous request
configXHR.send();

// Response status check
if(configXHR.status == 200) {
  var configs = JSON.parse(configXHR.responseText);
  console.log(configs);
} else {
  throw "Unable to load config file";
}

// Bootstrap your Vue application below
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> preferably resolved dynamically

One simple solution may rely on `HMR`, which allows load and dynamically update imported resource. And more, `Webpack + HMR` will watch automatically file on server, and post updates on client if happened.

Genre classic - https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/

```
import config from 'APP_CONFIG';
// Some code ...
if(module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('APP_CONFIG', () => {
  // Reaction to changes...
  }
}
```